# HTML button to a native bridge iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, native

I have an index.html page that has multiple buttons. I would like to be able to click on a button and it goes to the native side of the phone. To call it and do some action on the HTML page. I don't know how to do that?

In other words i would like to go from HTML to ios native actions and features, such as calling camera, gyro and so on.

Comment: I already loaded my local HTML files. it shows on the ios simulator, i would like to be able to click on a link open camera and it goes to the native side to open the camera how does that happen?

Comment: Why not you use Phonegap/cardova ? you can use the native plugins to call native side like camera.

Comment: I am trying to avoid outside third parties

Answer (score 0):

You have to make some changes in your html page.
Use image instead of button.Then use anchor tag around image tag.

Set href as "btn://btn1" or what you want to identify your button.

Ex.

```
<a href="btn://btn1"> <img src="test.png" ></a>
```

In ios side:

1.Assign delegate to your UIWebview.

2.Implement below method

```
    //Method when bookmark button  pressed
    - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType

    {

        if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"btn"])
        {
             //Enter your Code here
        }
        return YES;

    }
```

using above method you can identify witch button is clicked and according to that you can perform any action you want.

Comment: Do i add that in my App delegate or in my specific class?

Comment: You have to add this in your specific class.